# Multiple SQL Queries with python & flask

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, flask

I have a SQLite3 table that collects data from a gym booking form; all the data goes into one table - Name, Email, Day, Exercise Class, Class Time.

If it is possible, I would like to find a way to get all from Name if Day, Exercise Class & Class Time are equal to a selected value.

I am using Flask so once I can do this the data would then be used to generate a new HTML page (which would be the registration checklist page for the gym tutor).

I am pretty sure this is incorrect, but this is the general idea of what I would like to achieve..

```
db.execute("SELECT * FROM GymTable WHERE (Day == "Monday", Ex_Class == "BoxFit", Ex_Time == "0745-0845"))
```

Comment: . . You need to learn basic SQL syntax.  There are many resources online and offline to help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You may find these two tutorials on the [SQL WHERE clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) and [SQL AND, OR, NOT Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) helpful. Notice first that the equal operator is `=` instead of `==`. This query needs `AND` between column filters. The WHERE clause should not be enclosed in `()`. You may find the [python sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html) doc useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

the correct query in this case would be:

```
db.execute("SELECT * FROM GymTable WHERE Day = 'Monday' and Ex_Class = 'BoxFit' and Ex_Time = '0745-0845'")
```

Comment: `SELECT Name FROM` since Sinclair only wants to get names from Name column

Answer (score 1):

To better illustrate:

```
db.execute( "
    SELECT name 
    FROM   gymtable 
    WHERE  day = 'Monday' 
        AND ex_class = 'BoxFit' 
        AND ex_time = '0745-0845' 
");
```